# Ionic Framework for ios - Development Mode

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework to create an app. Previously I was working on Windows, but now I moved to Mac.

I already register with IOS developer program. Is there is any step by step tutorial available so I can test my app on my different iPhone devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you build your project with `ionic build ios` (of course, you first have to add the platform with `ionic platform add ios`) you will have a project file which you can open up with Xcode on your Mac.

From there you can easily simulate your app on various iOS devices (iPhone, iPad...), just look up a basics of how to use Xcode (here's one [official tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html)).

Ionic also provides you with the `ionic emulate ios` command which starts the iOS emulator with your app without you needing to run Xcode.

*edit:* Yes, you can use Ionic View for this. In the CLI there is an option to share your development app with someone else by simply doing `ionic share someone@email.com`

Comment: Can i publish my app on development mode . so different user can test it

Comment: Yes, you can use Ionic View for this. In the CLI there is an option to share your development app with someone else by simply doing `ionic share someone@email.com`. Btw, if the answer helped, consider it accepting.